# How to move up/down stack frames using Node.js built-in debugger

Tags: node.js, debugging

*I know node-inspector is popular. But I prefer the built-in node debugger for its simplicity and availability.*

In node.js built-in debugger, once a breakpoint is hit, how do I move up/down the stack frames as the [`up` and `down` commands](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/GDB-Commands.html) in `gdb`?

I noticed that the V8 debugging protocol [does support selecting frame](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/master/docs/debugger_protocol.md). But node.js debugger documentation mentions [it does not implement all the protocol specifies](https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html#debugger_debugger). So if this functionality is not available in the builtin debugger, what would be the workarounds?

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/nodejs/node-inspect/issues/47

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've found which isn't completely ideal. You can start to inspect the environment any time you want using the `repl` command in the debugger.

To move up the stack I haven't found a better way than to use the `out` command followed by repl. Obviously once you do this you can't get back down to where you were. So it is somewhat "destructive".

But this is much easier to use in a pinch than node-inspector which rarely works right for me.